# markdown-language-features : Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at Object.image

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I usually used a personnal extension to convert md file to pdf. Everything worked well in the past.

But now, when I try to used my extension (same version, no change was done), everything works well if I don't have image in my document.

If I've image, the extension crash with the following error :

```
stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined    at
Object.image (c:\Users\Damgot\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
Code\resources\app\extensions\markdown-language-features\dist\extension.js:1:98373)
    at s.renderInline (c:\Users\Damgot\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft
VS
Code\resources\app\extensions\markdown-language-features\dist\extension.js:1:141683)
    at s.render (c:\Users\Damgot\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
Code\resources\app\extensions\markdown-language-features\dist\extension.js:1:142055)
    at h.render (c:\Users\Damgot\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
Code\resources\app\extensions\markdown-language-features\dist\extension.js:1:103730)
```

I searched a lot about this problem and I found the error occurs only I use the following syntax for image :

```
![Exemple d'image](example.jpg)
```

If I used the following syntax everything works well :

```
<img src="example.jpg" alt="Texte alternatif" width="150"/>
```

Is it a change in the markdown language ? Or a change in the markdown part of visual studio code ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what if you use `![Texte alternatif](example.jpg)`

Comment: This syntax raises the error. Only the html syntax works.